# Setting explicit limits for rounding

Tags: python, numpy, rounding

Is there a more elegant way of setting an explicit rounding limit?

**What I'm using:**

```
arr= #original array
rnd_lim=1.7
rounded_arr=np.where(arr.__ge__(rnd_lim), arr,np.floor( arr))
rounded_arr=np.where(rounded_arr.__lt__(rnd_lim), rounded_arr,np.ceil(rounded_arr))
```

**Input:**

```
array([1.115, 1.722, 1.21 , 2.   , 1.025, 2.   , 1.269, 2.   , 1.349,
       1.952, 1.804, 1.871, 1.853, 1.992, 1.862, 2.   , 1.45 , 2.   ,
       1.089, 1.464, 1.011, 1.371, 1.001, 1.611, 1.341, 1.174, 1.012,
       1.076, 1.627, 1.266, 1.812, 2.   , 1.031, 1.675, 1.273, 1.093,
       2.   , 1.874, 1.281, 1.974, 1.043, 1.526, 2.   , 1.264, 1.153,
       1.01 , 1.893, 1.988, 1.42 , 1.284, 1.727, 2.   , 2.   , 1.93 ,
       1.789, 2.   , 1.084, 1.984])
```

**Output:**

```
array([1., 2., 1., 2., 1., 2., 1., 2., 1., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 1.,
       2., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 2., 2., 1., 1.,
       1., 1., 2., 2., 1., 2., 1., 1., 2., 1., 1., 1., 2., 2., 1., 1., 2.,
       2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 1., 2.])
```

**Sub question:**
The method I am currently using only woks with sets of numbers with a range of 1. Is there a method that only checks the decimal place, and therefore also works with more disparate sets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `np.divmod` to separate the whole numbers and fractions in each element. Then round the fractional parts using your method and recombine:

```py
>>> arr = np.array([0.6, 0.8, 1.6, 1.8, 2.6, 2.8])
>>> rnd_lim = 0.7
>>> whole, frac = np.divmod(arr, 1)
>>> rounded_fracs = np.where(frac.__ge__(rnd_lim), frac,np.floor(frac))
>>> rounded_fracs = np.where(rounded_fracs.__lt__(rnd_lim), rounded_fracs, np.ceil(rounded_fracs))
>>> rounded_fracs + whole
array([0., 1., 1., 2., 2., 3.])
```